# SQL one-to-many: get all rows with filters

Tags: sql

I've been trying to get this to work for a personal project for days and have no clue what I'm doing wrong:

What I want to do is get a list of all ideas (specifically idea_id) that aren't created by a user or voted on by that user

Idea table:

| id | idea | created_by |
| --- | --- | --- |

Votes Table

| id | voter_id | idea_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

There is a FK relationship between `idea.id` and `votes.idea_id`

I have global access to a users profile and can filter out simply by saying

```
where voter_id != auth.uid()
```

I've tried left join, inner join, outer join, union. I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Does anyone have any suggestions/solutions to this?

Left join gets me close, but of course because of the way left join works, this returns null for ideas that aren't voted on yet (which I need to see)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select id from idea where created_by!=auth.uid() and id not in (select  idea_id from Votes where voter_id = auth.uid())

Comment: Thanks! This was very close to what I wanted which led me to the correct answer. I updated it to be:
...and id not in (select idea_id from votes where voter_id = auth.uid())
because it's possible that votes don't exist yet on every idea. If you want to update your answer to that I can accept it. Appreciate your help

Comment: Great to know that this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think a subquery will get you there.

Here's an example using CTEs -

```
WITH USERS AS (
SELECT 11 USERID, 'Mary' FNAME UNION
SELECT 12 USERID, 'Peter' FNAME UNION
SELECT 13 USERID, 'Paul' FNAME 
),

IDEAS AS (
SELECT 1 IDEA_ID, 'Apples' IDEA, 11 CREATED_BY UNION
SELECT 2 IDEA_ID, 'Bananas' IDEA, 11 CREATED_BY UNION
SELECT 3 IDEA_ID, 'Oranges' IDEA, 11 CREATED_BY UNION
SELECT 4 IDEA_ID, 'Running' IDEA, 12 CREATED_BY UNION
SELECT 5 IDEA_ID, 'Swimming' IDEA, 12 CREATED_BY UNION
SELECT 6 IDEA_ID, 'Hiking' IDEA, 12 CREATED_BY UNION
SELECT 7 IDEA_ID, 'Watching TV' IDEA, 13 CREATED_BY UNION
SELECT 8 IDEA_ID, 'Sleep' IDEA, 13 CREATED_BY UNION
SELECT 9 IDEA_ID, 'Eating' IDEA, 13 
),

VOTES AS (
SELECT 21 VOTE_ID, 11 VOTER_ID, 1 IDEA_ID UNION
SELECT 22 VOTE_ID, 11 VOTER_ID, 6 IDEA_ID UNION
SELECT 23 VOTE_ID, 12 VOTER_ID, 7 IDEA_ID UNION
SELECT 24 VOTE_ID, 13 VOTER_ID, 8 IDEA_ID
)

--MAIN QUERY 
SELECT 
    *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            IDEAS.IDEA_ID,
            IDEAS.IDEA,
            IDEAS.CREATED_BY,
            VOTES.VOTE_ID,
            VOTES.VOTER_ID,
            VOTERS.FNAME VOTER_NAME,
            IDEA_CREATOR.USERID CREATOR_ID,
            IDEA_CREATOR.FNAME CREATOR_FNAME
        FROM IDEAS
        LEFT JOIN VOTES  ON IDEAS.IDEA_ID = VOTES.IDEA_ID
        LEFT JOIN USERS VOTERS ON VOTERS.USERID = VOTES.VOTER_ID
        LEFT JOIN USERS IDEA_CREATOR ON IDEA_CREATOR.USERID = IDEAS.CREATED_BY
    ) temp 
WHERE 
    --Exclude where Mary (11) is the voter or idea creator 
    (VOTER_ID IS NULL OR VOTER_ID <> 11)
    AND 
    (CREATOR_ID IS NULL OR CREATOR_ID <> 11)
```

The 'TEMP' subquery arranges your data so that it's easy to exclude based on voter or created by user info.

```
IDEA_ID IDEA    CREATED_BY  VOTE_ID     VOTER_ID    VOTER_NAME  CREATOR_ID  CREATOR_FNAME
1   Apples      11          21          11          Mary        11          Mary
2   Bananas     11          NULL        NULL        NULL        11          Mary
3   Oranges     11          NULL        NULL        NULL        11          Mary
4   Running     12          NULL        NULL        NULL        12          Peter
5   Swimming    12          NULL        NULL        NULL        12          Peter
6   Hiking      12          22          11          Mary        12          Peter
7   Watching TV 13          23          12          Peter       13          Paul
8   Sleep       13          24          13          Paul        13          Paul
9   Eating      13          NULL        NULL        NULL        13          Paul
```

Then you just define that in the where clause -

```
WHERE 
    --Exclude where Mary (11) is the voter or idea creator
    (VOTER_ID IS NULL OR VOTER_ID <> 11)
    AND 
    (CREATOR_ID IS NULL OR CREATOR_ID <> 11)
```

And the results are:

```
IDEA_ID IDEA    CREATED_BY  VOTE_ID     VOTER_ID    VOTER_NAME  CREATOR_ID  CREATOR_FNAME
4   Running     12          NULL        NULL        NULL        12          Peter
5   Swimming    12          NULL        NULL        NULL        12          Peter
7   Watching TV 13          23          12          Peter       13          Paul
8   Sleep       13          24          13          Paul        13          Paul
9   Eating      13          NULL        NULL        NULL        13          Paul
```